# The authenticity of host 'nodejs-xxxxx.rhcloud.com can't be established

Tags: git, ssh, rsa, openshift, redhat

I create new app in **www.openshift.redhat.com**. But When I clone repository to my computer it show following details

```
Cloning into 'xxxx'...
The authenticity of host 'xxxx-easychat.rhcloud.com (52.7.6.68)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

if I give it as "yes" repository can clone. But I can't commit.
It shows the following error:

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

So after that I add `id_rsa.pub` content to the https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/keys/new and save it.
But same thing happen.
When run the **rhc sshkey list** it show the same Fingerprint

What should I do?

Comment: Have you changed into the cloned directory?

Answer (score 1):

> But i can't commit.

Make sure you cd first in the repo, make some changes add them to the index (`git add`) and commit there.

See for instance the official `developers.openshift.com` doc "[Using the Git Repository](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-modifying-applications.html#using-git-repository)".